# Android WebView evaluateJavascript Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Currently I'm trying to figured out which is the best way to invoke javascript from android.

- AndroidJSCore. [AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore.git)
- WebView

I've tried AndroidJSCore, it's great. But it would enlarge the apk size.
Then I trying to dive into WebView to invoke javascript. But fail.

Activity look like this:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private static final String TAG = WebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jsWeb/test.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

            String test1 = "permissionRegist(\"'function'\", [\"'319609831167500021'\",\"'319609831167500022'\",\"'319609831167500023'\",\"'419609839767500020'\",\"'644731700926740003'\",\"'644731700926740004'\",\"'854885785357389824'\",\"'854995673156816896'\",\"'855001385022918656'\",\"'855009454683459584'\",\"'855298661779902464'\",\"'855303143108513792'\",\"'855347061611171840'\",\"'855356859882803200'\"])";
            String test2 = "evalJSExpression()";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript(test1, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        Log.d(TAG, s);
                    }
                });

                webView.evaluateJavascript(test2, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        Log.d(TAG, s);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

there appending files are:

android.js

```js
function permissionRegist(type, list) {
    var s_permissionMap = new Map();
    s_permissionMap.set(type, list);
}

function evalJSExpression() {
    var result = 'dddddd';
    return result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LogicalExpression</title>

    <!-- 导入script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="android.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--<button onClick="permissionRegist()">点击读取文件</button>-->
</body>

</html>
```

but the result is :

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/jsWeb/android.js (2)
 D/WebViewActivity: null
 D/WebViewActivity: "dddddd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/mozilla/rhino
here is an example : http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/04/05/Execute-JavaScript-in-Android-without-WebView/

Comment: Yep, I've tried. But it seems that not work well , then I turned to AndroidJSCore lib.

Comment: Have you tried react native. You might not be able to invoke javascript. But you can convert your javascript app into native and that can be invoked from your existing native app. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: We are trying to calculate some data through javascript function, so both android & iOS can use the javascript source code, of course , it is a small set of code. But other are native codes.  We are not considering using ReactNative yet.Due to some biz reasons... @NSK

Answer (score 0):

AndroidJSCore is a great lib for android to invoke javascript without WebView. 
It seems that Both Native WebView and rhino might have some compilable issues due to the different versions of javascript. 
Welcome to contact me about this.
I would find out why when I have time.